# Sprinkler solenoid won't activate

Tags: wiring, sprinkler-system

My sprinkler solenoid won't activate and I would like some advice on trobuleshooting. Here is a picture at the manifold: https://ibb.co/kRoR5Q

Here are the facts:

- The solenoid at the top, attached to the yellow wire, is the one I would like to turn on. Both it and the manifold are brand new.
- The solenoid at the bottom, attached to the red wire, does work.
- The one in the middle, attached to the orange wire, also does not work but I don't care about it.
- I measured voltage by putting a NCVT to each wire while it was activated using the controller. When measured at the controller, all three outgoing wires show voltage as expected when activated. However, when measured at the manifold, only the incoming red wire triggers the voltage tester.
- The other colored wires are also present at my controller, but they are not wired to any zones.

Any idea how I might troubleshoot this further? I am at a loss.

If there's no hope of resurrecting the yellow or orange wires, I would appreciate suggestions for workarounds. I was thinking that maybe the red wire could be "split" at the manifold to feed each of the three solenoids. Any suggestions to this end would be welcome as well.

Update: here is what I found at the other valve box: https://ibb.co/fvCkh5

I count 11 wire nuts, which would account for the seven zones, the three extra wires and the common wire.

Comment: Sounds like a broken wire somewhere, perhaps underground.  If there are other valves in the system and the wire goes to those valves first it may be that the connection corroded in another valve box, as you don't appear to be using moisture resistant wire nuts.  If there are no other valves in the system then it appears you have spare wires from the controller and maybe you can change to another wire.

Comment: Thanks. There are other valves in the system and the wire likely goes to this one last because it's at the corner of the property. What am I looking for in the other valve boxes? Presumably I won't see these particular colors of wires going to wire nuts except in this particular box. I will test the other unused wires tomorrow.

Comment: Yes you likely will.  The multi-conductor wire generally runs from the controller to one valve box and then the next.   Check each one and see.  Many times the installer will just peal back the outer jacket and get the colors they need at that location, other times every wire will be splices (the common wire, usually white but could be any color, will be connected to one side of every valve, while the valve wire will only connect at the controller and one valve.  Let me google for a visual that might help.

Comment: I didn't find a helpful diagram but typically one multi conductor cable leaves the controller (or maybe 2 one for "front" and one for "back" if it a large system).  That multi-conductor cable will snake its way valve box to valve box following the main waterline that brings water from one valve box to the next.

Comment: Thanks, Tyson. We have a 13-zone setup with two multi-conductor cables, one for the front and one for the back. This box is part of the back. I will check the other back box(es) tomorrow and report back. Am I looking for a splice of the yellow wire in a previous box that is corroded?

Comment: Check any other valve boxes between the controller and this one, you will find the multi-conductor cable runs thru it.

Comment: OK, I will find it. Should I be looking for corrosion in the yellow wire there? Maybe testing it there?

Comment: If it's spliced with a regular wire nut, that has likely corroded due to water.  If it's spliced with and underground splice or silicon filled wire nut take it apart and remake the connection.  If it runs straight thru with no splice then start noting what color wire you might want to switch to, i.e. Which colors are not used-- you can tell at the controller end, but just be sure it's spliced in intermediary valve boxes if it not straight thru.  Be sure to get filled wirenuts for this, or the underground splice kit, see the underground sprinkler isle at your favorite big box store.

Comment: So I'm hoping to find a splice or nut in the other valve box, right? If I see nothing there then I'm out of luck?

Comment: Look first, I think you'll understand when you see, if you don't snap pics and edit them in

Comment: Hi Tyson, I just edited in a picture of the other box. I see 11 wire nuts. Is the next step to rewire these? Would I just cut off the wire and reconnect it?

Comment: Start with that problematic yellow wire.  You're on the right track.  Check for voltage here as well

Comment: I just checked it. The yellow wire in this box does get voltage in response to the controller (yay!). So I imagine I have to rewire -- do I just cut, strip and reseat in the nut?

Comment: What do you mean by "one" of the yellow wires?  Does that mean on one side of the existing wire nut there is voltage but not on the other side?  If so then yes, cut the ends off, strip the ends, twist together, add WATERPROOF wire nut.  (This problem was caused by moisture getting in over time.)

Comment: Aha -- as soon as I laid hands on the yellow wire, I found a split in it just below the nut and inside the multi-conductor cable. I cannot be sure whether I myself caused the split -- if so, it must have been brittle to begin with because I grabbed it very gently. In any case, it looked difficult to splice because of the split's proximity to the multi-conductor cable. So I found a workaround: I attached one of the unused wires, a green wire, to the solenoid previously serviced by the yellow wire, after confirming that it was indeed receiving voltage. And now everything works! Many thanks.